# Django python rendering on dev but not on production

Tags: python, django, templates, view, rendering

I have development environment for running my new website with python manage.py runserver
and I have production environment that running this website with Apache2 and mod wsgi
I am sending some variables in my views.py that render successfully on my development env, but same code on the prod env render nothing to the template

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by setting:
ServerName mysite.com
in my apache config